# Using ejb annotations and CDI in a project where old EJB configurations are in ejb-jar.xml

Tags: java, ejb, cdi, java-ee-7

I have a legacy project with EJBs, where they are configured in `ejb-jar.xml`, like so:

```
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1">
    <session>
        <ejb-name>MyBean</ejb-name>
        <home>com.abby.api.RemoteBeanHome</home>
        <remote>com.abby.api.RemoteBean</remote>
        <ejb-class>com.abby.api.MyBean</ejb-class>
        <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
        <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    </session>
....
```

This works by means of looking up the JNDI tree. However, the server was upgraded to *Weblogic 12.2*, where *Java EE 7* is supported. So when injecting new **local EJB** to the remote session bean, `MyBean`, I am thinking of using merely the annotation, `@EJB`, without touching the existing XML deployment descriptor.

However, I get the following error:

```
The ejb-ref does not have an ejb-link and the JNDI name of the target bean has
not been specified. Attempts to automatically link the ejb-ref to its target 
bean failed because no EJBs in the application were found to implement the
"com.abby.api.NewBean" interface. Link or map this ejb-ref to its target EJB 
and ensure the interfaces declared in the ejb-ref are correct.
```

The new local stateless ejb code is the following:

```
@Stateless
public class TestEJB {
    public void test() {
        LOGGER.debug("I am the first EJB injected with CDI");
    }
}
```

My question is: In this case, is it still possible to add new EJBs with annotations instead of `ejb-jar.xml`?